# nested route not working for edit and delete rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, nested

I am trying to edit and delete book reviews of my book show page, but when I route to the edit page, it is making the book id the same as the review id. I can not figure out how to capture both params and pass them through the controller.

For example, I am on

/books/1

and I click edit to one of the reviews on that page and it takes me to

/books/37/reviews/37/edit

but it should take me to

/books/1/reviews/37/edit

then after editing it hits an error because book.id 37 does not exist saying No route matches [POST] "/books/37/reviews/37" which makes sense

Here's the code. Reviews are being made correctly so there must be something wrong with the nested routes. I think.

routes.rb

```
  get "/books/:id/reviews/:id/edit", to: "reviews#edit", as: "review_edit"
  patch "/books/:id/reviews/:id", to: "reviews#update"
  delete "/books/:id/reviews/:id", to: "reviews#destroy", as: "delete_review"
```

edit review form

```
  <%= form_for :review, url: {action: "update"} do |f| %>
     <h1 class="text-center">Edit yout thought</h1>

    <%= f.text_area :body, required: true, class: "form-control"%>
    <%= f.hidden_field :book_id, value: params[:id] %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.check_box(:spoiler) %>
      <%= label_tag( "SPOILER ALERT") %>
      <%= f.submit "Edit Thought", class: "btn btn-primary pull-right" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

I've tried changing the

```
url: {action: "update"}
```

to

```
url: review_edit_path(@book.id, review.id)
```

and I tried that with many different possible param syntax, [:id], without the @ etc. But it didn't work.

reviews controller

class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

```
        before_action :set_user, only: [:index, :create]
        before_action :set_book, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
        before_action :current_review, only: [:update, :destroy]

        def index
            @reviews = Review.hash_tree
        end

        def new
            @review = Review.new(parent_id: params[:parent_id]) 
        end

        def create  
            if params[:review][:parent_id].to_i > 0
                parent = Review.find_by_id(params[:review].delete(:parent_id))
                @review = parent.children.build(review_params)
                @review.user = current_user
            else
                @review = Review.new(review_params)
                @review.user = current_user
            end

            if @review.save
                flash[:success] = 'Your comment was successfully added!'
            else
                render 'new'
            end

            redirect_to book_path(@book)
        end

        def edit
        end

        def update
            @review.update_attributes(review_params)
        end

        def destroy
            @review.destroy
        end

        private

            def review_params
                params.require(:review).permit(:body, :spoiler, :book_id, :user_id)
            end

            def set_book
                @book = Book.find_by_id(params[:id])
            end

            def current_review
                @review = Review.find_by_id(params[:review_id])
            end
    end
```

I put the whole controller in so you can see what does work. Here I've changed the

```
def current_review
```

method to every permutation I could think of and it doesn't work either.

I also changed wether or not set_book and current_review methods run prior to edit, update or destroy and no combination has been right.

review model - I don't think is relevant, but in case in needs something else ...

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user

  has_closure_tree order: 'created_at DESC'

end
```

_review.html.erb I just realized the problems probably in the button itself, this could be the problematic code

```
  <% if review.user.id == session[:user_id] %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", review_edit_path(@book.id, review.id), method: "get", class: "pull-right btn btn-primary col-xs-2" %>
    <%= link_to "Delete", delete_review_path(@book.id, review.id) ,method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete ythis review?"}, class: "btn btn-danger col-xs-2 pull-right" %>
  <% end %>
```

The request to edit a review comes from the book show, so here's the book show method, in case it's relevant.

```
def show
  @reviews = Review.hash_tree
end
```

Comment: go to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, and start reading from `2.7 Nested Resources`, you basically need to use different identifiers for each `id`.

Comment: I'll check it out, I read a different doc, this one seems a little more helpful

Answer (score 0):

Nest your resources, like this:

routes.rb

```
resources :books do
       resources :reviews do
```

This will allow you to have a route like the one you want:

/books/1/reviews/37/edit

Your params will look like

```
{books_id:'1', id:'37'}
```

By the way, if you create the routes using resources, they will automatically be set to the create, show, update, delete methods on the controller, no need for you to set them to a particular method (and makes for a cleaner controller).

Comment: my sites to developed to go back and switch my routes to the rails auto scaffold version. i'd have to change all my view oaths. If I really can't figure out another solution, I will try it. I also like seeing all my routes in the routes.rb file. The scaffolded routes are almost to clean for me. I know you can always rake them, but I like being able to see them in file.